# displaying array output within repeat loop in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm working on an exercise in Swift 3 Playground.

I have an array called sums with a bunch of numbers in. I want to cycle through each of the array items and print 'The sum is: x' but I'm getting a generic error with the print command.

```
var i = 0
repeat {
    print ("the sum is: \(sums[i])")
    i = i + 1
} while i <= sums.count
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

It must be done in a repeat loop as that's what the exercise is asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sums.count will give you the size of the array.
Arrays are 0-indexed in Swift.  You're accessing out of the array range.
Check for sums.count - 1 or:

```
var i = 0
repeat {
    print ("the sum is: \(sums[i])")
    i = i + 1
} while i < sums.count
```

Comment: Ugh, can't believe that's all it was, i thought I was going mad! Thanks for that.